# connecting led halo lights on 2006 accord

Tags: honda, accord, headlight, wiring, led

I am installing Spyder projector LED halo headlights on a 2006 Honda Accord. Following the install instructions I twisted together the two red wires and black wires respectively from the LED halo lights. Using t-tap connectors I combined the twisted led halo red pair to the white (positive) wire coming off the low beam light and the black twisted pair to the black(negative) wire coming off the low beam light. Instructions then tell you to connect the spliced red/white combination to the parking light wire on the turn signal harness. There are three wires on the turn signal harness. A positive for the turn signal flasher, a black negative wire in the center and a positive for the parking lights. To determine which positive wire is which they instruct you to use a multimeter. Place the black probe to the black plug socket of the turn signal harness and then place the red probe to either the of the positive plug sockets. If the meter shows a pulsing/fluctuating voltage that is supposed to be the turn signal. A steady voltage reading indicates that wire is for the parking light. 
I attempted this and with the black multimeter probe touching the black socket I touched one of the positive sockets. I heard a sizzle and my turn signal and parking lights appeared to short out. Not sure what I did wrong there. So question one is how to determine the correct wire without shorting the circuit.

I thought the fix would be to replace the relay for the turn signal/hazards. I got the part and did this but the turn signal/hazards/parking lights did not come on. Therefore the second question is what else could be preventing the turn signal et al lights from coming back on other than the relay?
Thanks

Comment: Fuse  blown.  And get the wiring diagram for your car

Comment: When you do the test on the parking/turn connector, make sure your meter is set to read voltage, not current - red probe should be in the Volts/Ohms socket.